# Saleae logic analyzer, exporting data to .csv file

Tags: digital-logic

I have bought Saleae Logic Analyzer, everything is good except the fact that when I try to export data to .csv file and then open it using MS Excel I get all data in one column. I would like to get Time, Data ,Read/Write, etc. in separate columns to further process it.

Comment: Why not just ask Saleae? They have a nice support forum/form on their site. Excel also has a text to column function that will split the data into separate columns for you. Just requires that the data is separated by spaces or commas. Could just use that to split it out.

Comment: Text to column function did the work, I have never heard about it. Thank you.

Comment: Assuming it does have commas in the file also make sure the file extenstion is CSV, it seems to affect how Excel handles them by default.

Answer (score 3):

Since you did not bother to show the format of the data being presented to Excel we can only guess at what the problem could be. I can see two possibilities here.

1. Put the data into a text file instead and then use Excel's very robust text file import wizard to perform the data import.
2. Write a pre-processing script on the PC in something like Perl, Python, C or even the VBA macro language available inside Excel to read in the data from the logic analyzer and convert it to a true .CSV format to that it will open directly in Excel.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would be to use Excels text to column function : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-text-into-different-cells-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US 
Not a "real" solution to the base problem, but should be a decent work around.

I looked through Saleae's forums and they implied that there were export options to put data in separate columns in csv format, but they didn't expand on that so you'd have to contact them to get details.